# How can I convert parquet-dotnet's columns to individual models?

Tags: c#, parquet.net

parquet-dotnet has an example I'm trying to work with that looks like this:

```
using (Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("c:\\test.parquet"))
{
   using (var parquetReader = new ParquetReader(fileStream))
   {
      DataField[] dataFields = parquetReader.Schema.GetDataFields();

      for(int i = 0; i < parquetReader.RowGroupCount; i++)
      {
         using (ParquetRowGroupReader groupReader = parquetReader.OpenRowGroupReader(i))
         {
            DataColumn[] columns = dataFields.Select(groupReader.ReadColumn).ToArray(); 
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The concern I have is with the `columns` line. If I have data that looks like this, from a table perspective:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test1 |
| 1 | Test2 |

I want to map this data from the parquet file to a model that looks exactly like that. The issue that I have is that the data comes out from `columns` looking like this:

```
columns[0].Data[0] - 1
columns[0].Data[1] - 1

columns[1].Data[0] - Test1
columns[1].Data[1] - Test2
```

This might be a little hard to understand, but essentially, the `columns` variable is a collection of properties that has an array of values. That array is every value in the table for that column. So I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to match the data in each array position with the data in the same array position in a different column and still keep everything together.

Also, I'm unable to do the normal deserialize because I have properties in the parquet file that look weird like `__$something`, so I can't map those to a similarly named property. Any ideas?

Comment: You can access the columns by name instead of number   : datarow.Column["Col A"]

Comment: @jdweng Doesn't seem like it. I get a `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'`` error, implying we can only use integers with parquet-dotnet. Each column has a Field property with this info, but I'm not sure how this would help me.

Comment: Try : datarow.Field<int>("Col A")

Comment: @jdweng I can try that, but I don't know what you're trying to get at. I don't understand how this would help solve my issue.